# How to generate pojos with default constructor and setters

Tags: java, code-generation, jooq

Firstly, is this is a good idea (to generate/use pojo with default constructor and setters) ?
If yes, how is it possible by using the code generator ?

I'm using the nu.studer.jooq Gradle plugin (https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin) with jooq 3.11.9 and a postgres db.

```
// Generator
jooq {
  version = '3.11.9'
  edition = 'OSS'
  sample(sourceSets.main) {
    jdbc {
      driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
      url = 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb'
      user = 'myuser'
      password = 'mypwd'
//      properties {
//        property {
//          key = 'ssl'
//          value = 'true'
//        }
//      }
    }
    generator {
      name = 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator'
      strategy {
        name = 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGeneratorStrategy'
      }
      database {
        name = 'org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase'
        inputSchema = 'public'
        forcedTypes {
          forcedType {
            name = 'varchar'
            expression = '.*'
            types = 'JSONB?'
          }
          forcedType {
            name = 'varchar'
            expression = '.*'
            types = 'INET'
          }
        }
      }
      generate {
        relations = true
        deprecated = false
        records = true
        immutablePojos = true
        fluentSetters = true
      }
      target {
        packageName = 'com.project.generated'
        directory = 'src/main/java'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank in advance for your ideas and advices.

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly, is this is a good idea (to generate/use pojo with default constructor and setters) ?

A good idea for doing what? The jOOQ code generator doesn't judge you. Using default constructors and getters/setters is one supported flavour. Immutable POJOs is the other one.

> If yes, how is it possible by using the code generator ?

Turn off the genreation of `immutablePojos`

```
pojos = true
immutablePojos = false
```

Note that you don't have to turn that off. The default is for them to be turned off.

Comment: It was so simple... Don't know why, I didn't found the solution in the documentation. I will check. Thank you very much. I need the default constructor and setters because some pojos have a long list of properties but only a few are mandatory : purely aesthetic

Answer (score 0):

I just released a code generator which does exactly what you want. (If i got you right)

Try https://github.com/carstenSpraener/cgV19 ist has a PoJo generator in it's HelloWorld exammple. Supports

- gradle plugin
- modular model loader
- "cartridges" for different needs:

  - cartridgeA: PoJo in Java
  - cartridgeB: PoJo in TypeScript

Comment: Based on the domain/URL of your link(s) being the same as, or containing, your user name, you appear to have linked to your own content. If you do so, you need to disclose that it's yours. If you don't disclose that it's your own content, it's often considered spam. See: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182212/what-signifies-good-self-promotion-or-self-promotion-part-infinity) and [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).